# How can i write a regex for googlebot redirection in nginx

Tags: regex, angularjs, nginx, seo, search-engine

Its an angular app, for search engine crawling I have written a rule in nginx configurations like if a search engine bot is trying to hit a site then It will redirected to some php page and that will serve a static html page. Previously I have written like

```
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "(googlebot|yahoo|bingbot)"){
        rewrite /(.*) <<Site domain>>/metainfo.php?id=$1;
    }
}
```

Google search was showing code instead of meta description in google search result

[image]

But Google bot was not crawling, It was showing code in google search result.Then I added **'Googlebot/2.1'** to user agent list

```
location / {
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "(googlebot|Googlebot\/2.1|yahoo|bingbot)"){
        rewrite /(.*) <<Site domain>>/metainfo.php?id=$1;
    }
}
```

**Now Google serach showing meta information in search result for site. But This wont be a fix and proper solution as I have written a googlebot with its version.Surely It version will change after so I want help to write regex so that version change wont affect implementation ?**

Any help appreciated

Comment: It's not clear, what you want.

Comment: @AlexeyTen In second implementation, you can see 'Googlebot\/2.1' which is solving my problem. But if another version come then it wont work so I am thinking to write regex for googlebot user aget . Event it hit site with any version It will redirect to metainfo.php.